# 15.10 Dolphin: R-click anything -> mouseover "Activities" = Dolphin disappears/insta-crash

Tags: kde

This started just recently.

In Dolphin if I right-click on a file or folder and then move my mouse cursor over the "Activities" selection, even fleetingly, Dolphin will instantaneously shut down.

The "Send via Bluetooth" or "Properties" options work fine. But if you even **think** of touching "Activities" on your way there -- **boop**. Gone.

Symptoms:
Sometimes I hear a slight blip of disk activity right as Dolphin crashes.
The "Activities" sub-menu *never* opens. It crashes too quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I disabled the **File to activity linking plugin** service by going into Dolphin's **Control** -> **Configure Dolphin** and in the **Services** Tab, now the error is gone.